# Android how to get string from clipboard onPrimaryClipChanged?

Tags: android, clipboard, clipboardmanager

I'm trying to get text copied into the clipboard using the following listener:

```
import android.content.ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener;
import com.orhanobut.logger.Logger;

public class ClipboardListener implements OnPrimaryClipChangedListener
{

    public void onPrimaryClipChanged()
    {
        // do something useful here with the clipboard
        // use getText() method
        Logger.d("Clipped");
    }
}
```

The listener is initialized as follows:

```
ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener( new ClipboardListener());
```

After the text is copied into the clipboard `onPrimaryClipChanged` is fired, but I don't know how to get the copied text in this method using [ClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html#getPrimaryClip()%22getPrimaryClip()%22) because the method is not available from the context and is not passed in the param of `onPrimaryClipChanged`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest adding the listener as follows instead of creating a new class. I have included how to get text from the ClipData.

You mention being unable to access your context in the listener, I've added a comment within the code below showing how to do so.

```
ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
        ClipData clipData = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip();
        ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(0);
        String text = item.getText().toString();

        // Access your context here using YourActivityName.this
    }
});
```

Comment: It throws null pointer exception:
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: You'll probably have to add a safety check for item.getText() being null incase there is no text in the ClipBoard when onPrimaryClipChanged is fired.

Comment: Is there any way to get this kind ClipBoard data in iOS ?? @KarenForde

Comment: @TapanKumarPatro I don't know sorry, I'm not an iOS developer