# How to access clipboard data in Android?

Tags: java, android, clipboard

How do i get data from clip board. I want to get data and show in toast.Means In my android phone in any edit text .. When will long press and copy some string value .. That's should toast. How can i achieve this ?? In every tutorial i get, they copy from specify editText. I want like where ever in my phone i will copy some text .. I just need to get assess that particular string ...
And `clipboard.getText();`also not working.

I tried

```
public class ClipBoardDataManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public ClipBoardDataManager() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String callNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

            ClipData myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", clipboard.getText());
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);


            ClipData abc = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
            ClipData.Item item = abc.getItemAt(0);

            Toast.makeText(ctx,item.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }
```

and register.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter1 = new IntentFilter(String.valueOf(Intent.FILL_IN_CLIP_DATA));

ctx.registerReceiver(clipBoardDataManager,intentFilter1);
```

Still i am not getting it .. Please help!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38214507/7320259 try this

Comment: How it will keep assess for all the edittext of my phone ? and my Service class is ok ?? I tried onPrimaryClipChanged() but not working

Comment: @ZakiPathan Sorry brother for that time.. Now it worked .. Type in answer i will make as a correct one

Comment: thanks. please check my answer below. will gives upvote to this question ;)

Answer (score 12):

### Java

```
ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
        ClipData clipData = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip();
        ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(0);
        String text = item.getText().toString();

        // Access your context here using YourActivityName.this
    }
});
```

### Kotlin

```
val clipBoardManager = context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
clipBoardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener {
    val copiedString = clipBoardManager.primaryClip?.getItemAt(0)?.text?.toString()
    // Your code
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `clipBoard` in Koltlin version stands for which variable?

Comment: @MarkDelphi I assume they meant `clipBoardManager` in place of `clipBoard`

Comment: @Tamarisk Yes, that makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin

Clean, reusable, and simple working solution using Extension function -

```
fun Context.getFromClipBoard() : String? {
    val clipBoardManager = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
    return clipBoardManager.primaryClip?.getItemAt(0)?.text?.toString()
}
```